# Perl scripts can't access Demon Access database to INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE, but allows me to search and display??. . . HELP?

Tags: perl, ms-access, scripting

My INSERT, DELETE statements won't work and I dont know why . . . in fact it's driving me crazy.  Please see my attached scrpits.  I have been using the Open Perl IDE as well as Notebook++ to contrast and work on these scripts.  As far as I can tell there is nothing the matter with them and it's driving me nuts.  I have checked the file permissions for the database.  I can search for information in the database and display all the items in the database but I cant INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE.

Below find the link to my page (formatting of the page will be better when I can get some functionality):
http://129.2.168.163/cm485a2/project1.html

Please help.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w


use strict;
#use DBI;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);  # provide descriptive error messages
use Win32::ODBC;  #use ODBC package vs. DBI as in text

print header(); # print out "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"

# Get user's desired action from form
my $action = param('form_action');

# Connect to database
my $db = new Win32::ODBC("DSN=rreAccesscm485a2; UID=cm485a; PWD=kbradford68g")
     or die Win32::ODBC::Error();

my $cust_ID;
    my $fName;
my $mI;
my $lName;
my $street;
my $city;
my $state; 
my $zip_Code;
my $DOB;
my $agent_ID;
my $home_Phone;
my $cell_Phone;
my $profession;
my $employer;
my $referrer;

$cust_ID     = param('cust_ID');
$fName = param('first_Name');
    $mI = param('mI');
    $lName = param('last_Name');
    $street = param('street_Name');
    $city = param('city');
    $state = param('state');
    $zip_Code = param('zip_Code');
    $DOB = param('DOB');
    $agent_ID = param('agent_ID');
    $home_Phone = param('home_Phone');
    $cell_Phone = param('cell_Phone');
    $profession = param('profession');
    $employer = param('employer');
    $referrer = param('referrer');
    my $sql;

    $sql  = qq{INSERT INTO customer (Customer ID, first_Name, mI, last_Name,};
    $sql .= qq{street_Name, city, state, zip_Code, DOB};
    $sql .= qq{agent_ID, home_Phone, cell_Phone, profession, employer, referrer)};

    $sql .= qq{ VALUES ('$cust_ID','$fName','$mI','$lName','$street','$city',};
    $sql .= qq{'$state','$zip_Code','$DOB','$agent_ID','$home_Phone','$cell_Phone',};
    $sql .= qq{'$profession', '$employer', '$referrer')};

    #print '$sql=' . $sql . "\n";
    if ($db->Sql($sql)) 
    {
print "SQL Error: " . $db->Error() . "\n";
    print qq(<html><head><title>Database Error</title>
</head>
    <body><center><font size="6">Error with database call.</font>
    <hr />
    <font size="4" color="red">ODBC DB Error</font><br />
    <font size="3">Please hit your <b>Back</b> button to re-enter the data and try    again.</font></center>
    </body>
</html>);
exit;
}

sub Display_Page {
print qq(<html><head><title>Record Added!</title></head>
         <body>
            <center>
            <font size="6">Record Added!</font>
            <hr />
            <font size="4">
            <a href="http://129.2.168.163/cm485a2/project1.html">Back to Main Page</a>
            </font><br />
            </center>
         </body>
      </html>);
}
```

Comment: This is open to SQL injection. Please see http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote `Customer ID` or change the column name so that it doesn't contain spaces.

You also have to make sure you have a comma (`,`) after every column. It's missing after the `DOB` column name.

Comment: $sql  = qq{INSERT INTO customer (custID, firstName, mI, lastName,};
    $sql .= qq{streetName, city, state, zipCode, DOB};
    $sql .= qq{agentID, homePhone, cellPhone, profession, employer, referrer)};
   
    $sql .= qq{ VALUES ('$custID','$fName','$mI','$lName','$street','$city',};
    $sql .= qq{'$state','$zipCode','$DOB','$agentID','$homePhone','$cellPhone',};
    $sql .= qq{'$profession', '$employer', '$referrer')};

Comment: I changed the database names like you suggested and removed the spaces (& underscores for that matter) as shown above, however, it is now giving me a [SQL Error: [-3520] [1] [0] "[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Number of query values and destination fields are not the same."
Error with database call. ODBC DB Error]  However, have 15 query values and 15 destination cells in my Access database.

Comment: Okay, watched BLEACH and had a chance to chill out for a second. . . Anyway, I added the comma after DOB and found anther place that needed a comma and now I get this error messge:SQL Error: [-3703] [1] [0] "...Text must include 1 upper case “C” and 7 numerical digits larger than or equal to 0" Error with database call.  So here is the problem with this messsage: I am doing just that.  I set up this database and I know I have to use a C and 7 numerical digits larger than or equal to 0. What the??? . . .All guidance is appreciated:)

Comment: @Mike: You have some sort of trigger or constraint built into your database which is generating that error message. Either it is misconfigured or your `INSERT` statement has the column names misaligned with the values.

Comment: Okay, so check this out: I inserted a print statement to see my string and this is what I got:$sql=INSERT INTO customer (custID, firstName, mI, lastName,streetName, city, state, zipCode, DOBagentID, homePhone, cellPhone, profession, employer, referrer) VALUES ('','','M','','','Hogwartz','OH','','1/12/1972','','','','Writer', 'Herald Books', 'George Clooney') SQL Error: [-3520] [1] [0] "[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Number of query values and destination fields are not the same."
Error with database call. ODBC DB Error
WHAT THE???

Comment: Of course, I entered values in all of the fields.  Somehow my values are not getting into their respective variables. And the rabbit hole gets deeper . . .

Comment: @Mike: Do you see `DOBagentID`? You're still missing a comma. Also, you should print the environment variables at the top of the page so you can see if all of your form data is being sent.

Comment: Yeah, I caught the DOBagentID right away.  I will look into the environment variable thing.  Thanks!

Comment: I added the environmental printing into this script & it helped me see that I had not changed the variable names in the actual html form to coincide with the new database columsn!  Dooh. . .once i fixed that my INSERT string is okay.

Comment: However, I am trying to figure out another error message:"The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again." Is there any way that I can see what values they are talking about? I am using a new CustID and an existing agentID from my AGENT table. I even tried using a new agentID, however, both get the same error.

Comment: There's no easy way to know what key or index they're talking about. You'll have to do that yourself by looking at the indexes, keys, and relationships on the table and seeing if the data exists.